# Simplemodal with iframe not redirecting

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, simplemodal

My site is built on the zend framework. I have a link on my site that opens an iframe in order for a user to post to twitter. I can load the iframe just fine, but if the user has not yet authorized twitter, the iframe redirects to the twitter authorization page, and then back to my site.

When I test the flow by hitting the page directly that loads into the iframe, everything works fine. However, within the iframe, the redirects do not load, so the iframe is simply a blank page.

My redirect from within the page loaded in the iframe looks like this:

```
return $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={$session->token}");
```

Comment: Iframes are independent structures in a webpage. Do you redirect back to your main page or the iframe page?

Comment: Well, the twitter oauth protocol simply redirects within the page that loads, meaning that within the iframe, it should redirect back to my site within the iframe. However, the iframe never loads the twitter oath page. It's just a blank iframe.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if your iFrame works correctly. Can you edit your question and add the code for the iframe in your layout or script page?

Comment: Well it turns out that Twitter doesn't allow iframes. How do I mark this as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason, twitter has disabled this, is that you can't see the address bar in an iframe. So web apps could do easy fishing: telling the user to input his/her twitter user/passw into a form which just looks like the twitter sign in form, but is in fact hosted on the fishing server.